# Erlang cookie vs inter-node TLS communication in a RabbitMQ cluster

Tags: encryption, rabbitmq, cluster-computing

RabbitMQ supports ["TLS for Inter-node (Clustering) Traffic"](https://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering-ssl.html) and the usage of a shared secret known as the ["Erlang cookie"](https://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering.html#erlang-cookie). I understand that SSL/TLS is based on a combination of asymmetric and symmetric cryptography while the erlang cookie is solely based on symmetric cryptography, but what I fail to understand from the documentation is what these are used for.

Are they just 2 ways of achieving the same thing, ie inter-node encryption? or does the erlang cookie provide encryption for data traffic while TLS gives encryption for signalling/admin/overhead traffic?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to this question on the [Erlang Solutions blog](https://www.erlang-solutions.com/blog/erlang-distribution-over-tls.html):

> The “distribution protocol” is the means by which multiple Erlang
>   nodes join together to form a cluster. When Erlang nodes are
>   clustered, any process can send messages to processes on any other
>   node, and spawn new processes on any other node. This forms the basis
>   for distributed applications such as Mnesia, the database
>   implementation that comes with Erlang/OTP, and RabbitMQ, the message
>   broker.
>
> The Erlang distribution protocol was designed assuming that it’s
>   running on a trusted network. **While nodes connecting to each other are
>   required to prove that they possess a shared secret, called a
>   “cookie”, this is mostly aimed at ensuring that different Erlang
>   clusters on the same network don’t accidentally merge; it’s not
>   recommended to rely on the cookie mechanism to keep an attacker out.**